# How to fix port number in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webforms, web-hosting

I have two different project in one solution 
    1. Asp.net Project
    2. Mvc Project

In Asp.net **URL** : http://localhost:54172/View/Dashboard.aspx 
In Mvc **URL** : http://localhost:54177/EmployeeDetail/Index?Id=1

Asp.Net Port - 54172 
MVC Port - 54177

Now I want to redirect asp.net project to mvc project but because of port number change redirection is not perform

I want to fix same port number for both project

What can I do for fix port number for both project & redirection will drive smoothly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution is here,

Both Asp.net & mvc application will be host in different post, so we can fix port for both 
Asp.net & mvc and allow to use vise versa. That port will be set in web.config

**Asp.Net Project**

Fix port in **Asp.Net** for **MVC** in Web.Config ,
Mvc project port should be set here for asp.net

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="MvcApplication" value="http://localhost:54177" />  
</appSettings>
```

Access **web.config string in your page** where ever it needed

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MvcApplication"].ToString()<br>
```

Use that string in **master page**

```
<li><a class="nav-link" href="<%= GetUrl() %>" >Add User</a>
```

Set Dynamic url in GetUrl in **MasterPage.Master.cs**

```
    protected string GetLink()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MvcApplication"].ToString() + "/UserDetail/Index";
    }
```

**MVC Project**

Fix port in **MVC** for **Asp.Net** in Web.Config ,
Asp.net project port should be set for mvc

```
 <appSettings>    
     <add key="AspDotNetApplicaiton" value="http://localhost:54172" />
</appSettings>
```

Access **web.config string in your page** where ever it needed

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AspDotNetApplicaiton"].ToString()
```

Use that string in **Layout Page**

```
@{
    var AspDotNetProject = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AspDotNetApplicaiton"].ToString();
 }
```

Use that web config string in view **hyperlink**

```
 <li><a href="@AspDotNetProject/View/ContactUs.aspx">Conatact Us</a></li>
```

User that web config string in controller

```
 string redirectUrl = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AspDotNetApplicaiton"].ToString() + "/View/Dashboard.aspx");       
 return Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

here we can achieve redirect Asp.net webform to mvc in different project !!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to different domain, make sure both projects are running simultaneously.

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:54177/EmployeeDetail/Index?Id=1");
```

Comment: I want to use same port number for both project

Comment: You can't do that. :)

Comment: Is there any way to fix port in configure or anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not configure 2 difference web projects use same port.